# Xalan XSD Transform taking too long

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xalan, gml

I'm trying to use the GML XSLT subset tool to transform the GML XSD Schema. Platform is Windows 7 32-bit.

It gets stuck on the first command (at least 10 hours so far on my desktop):

```
>xalan -o gml.dep gml.xsd depends.xslt
```

Is there an option which would speed up a schema-aware transform?

Alternative tools that have been tried: Saxon HE, Altova XMLSpy. Both run out of memory on the GML schema.

EDIT: A few more facts:

1. GML version is 3.2.1
2. GML XSLT Subset tools are from Annex G in the spec
3. XSLT tools use XSLT version 1.0

Comment: Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor and Saxon HE is an XSLT 2.0 processor, but not schema-aware, so why do you ask about "an option which would speed up a schema-aware transform"? Simply processing an XSD schema as the input is not schema-aware processing. As for the memory problem, with a Java application there are command line options to increase the memory, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html. How large is that input document, which memory have you granted to the Java application when running Saxon?

Answer (score 1):

Solving performance problems requires detail, and you haven't given any detail. For starters, how big is the source document (that is, the GML schema), and how much memory are you allocating?

Given that you are trying to process XSD files as your input, and this is usually a complex task, I imagine that the main problem is the algorithmic complexity of the stylesheet. That kind of problem can often be solved with judicious use of keys.

I would be surprised if the GML schema is more than a few megabytes in size, so the memory problem is unlikely simply to be the size of the source document; it's more likely to be temporary data structures created within the stylesheet itself. But there's no way one can solve this one without access to the code.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am honoured to have a creator of Saxon reply to my query! Thank you. The GML schema is indeed only ~400kb on disk but I suspect it includes online schemas. The XSLT subset tool is in Annex G of the 3.2.1 spec as I noted above, but for reference I've included all GML xsd files and xslt files here: [link](http://public.lsdavies.mailc.net/GML/gml_3_2_1.zip). The command I used in SaxonEE was >Transform -o:gml.dep gml.xsd depends.xslt

Comment: I'm not going to get around to it today, and I don't have a way of flagging SO posts for future attention, so please raise this as a support request on http://saxonica.plan.io.